# Use Quicklook to see the Content of .JSON files?

Tags: finder, quicklook

Currently, I can use the space bar to preview a number of files such as .txt, .css, .html etc in Quick Look.  I cannot, however, see the actual contents of a .json file.

Is there any possible way to see the contents of .json files through space bar preview in finder?
(I'm Using OSX 10.8.4)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Download [a release of **qlstephen** from Github](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen/releases), and load it into the /Library/Quicklook or ~/Library/QuickLook folder. Then, restart the Dock.

I use this all the time when previewing JSON files, and it works great.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks. One thing to add for terminal n008s like myself, restart the dock with the command "killall Dock".

Comment: The library get's my vote simply for the answer to its' [Why "QLStephen"?](https://github.com/whomwah/qlstephen#why-qlstephen) headline.

Answer (score 45):

The home brew team has packaged **qlstephen**

```
brew install —-cask qlstephen
```

Comment: I had to first `brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask`.  Works great!

Comment: `brew cask install qlstephen && killall Dock` works for me, thanks!

Comment: I didn't even need to `killall Dock` on Mojave. Thanks

Comment: new syntax is ```brew install --cask qlstephen```

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [quicklook-json](http://www.sagtau.com/quicklookjson.html) plugin. If you want to install it via homebrew, run

```
brew cask install quicklook-json
```

which requires a running

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
```

if you never did that before.

Comment: Actually, vanilla brew search quicklook only returns quicklook-json as related to Json.

Answer (score 7):

Run `brew cask install quicklook-json` to Preview JSON files.

There are bunch of other usefull here, check following awesome list
https://github.com/sindresorhus/quick-look-plugins

Or install with following

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
brew cask install qlcolorcode qlstephen qlmarkdown quicklook-json qlprettypatch
brew cask install quicklook-csv betterzipql qlimagesize webpquicklook suspicious-package
```

Comment: one of the best links ever... :)  wish I had some spare points to give

Comment: @mlo55 just enjoy the quick looks !

Answer (score 1):

Macports provides an adequate port: `sudo port install QLStephen`.